# I have created a date using SimpleDateFormat, how do I convert into a string?

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

```
newDate =(newDaysAdded+"/"+month+"/"+year); 
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try {
  Date newDateOne = date.parse(newDate);
```

When I try:

```
view.writeToScreen(newDateOne);
```

I get the error:

```
 Incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to String.
```

Here is the writeToScreen method:

```
void writeToScreen(String s);
```

However from there I can't turn into a string, I have tried:
String test = Date.toString(newDateOne);

Can anyone help?

Comment: isn't the `newDate` already in the format you want? what do you need a formatter for?

Comment: `writeToScreen` expects a String and you are passing a Date...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your existing code you could use:

```
writeToScreen (date.format(newDateOne));
```

Comment: however now when I print it to the screen I get the full "Sat Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT 1997" where as I'd like it to be 01/11/1997. Is there a way I can just access those parts specifically and just print them in that format?

Comment: Hmmm.... I think I'd need to see the whole code, as that ought to work if placed in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
view.writeToScreen(newDateOne);
```

to

```
view.writeToScreen(newDateOne.toString());
```

Comment: Thankyou this worked however now when I print it to the screen I get the full "Sat Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT 1997" where as I'd like it to be 01/11/1997. Is there a way I can just access those parts specifically and just print them in that format?

Comment: @JakeWells whats your input `newDate =(newDaysAdded+"/"+month+"/"+year);` for this line? and what does `writeToScreen` does?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at all the methods... Either in the API doc or even in the intellisense in a code editor

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newDaysAdded = "05";
        String month = "04"; 
        String year = "2014";
        String newDateString = (newDaysAdded+"/"+month+"/"+year);

        SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            Date newDate = SDF.parse(newDateString); //Takes string and convert it to date

            //If i understand the question you dont just want to print it as a date...
            System.out.println(newDate);   //Sat Apr 05 00:00:00 CAT 2014

            //You want to print it as a string inf the format you specified in the SDT
            System.out.println(SDF.format(newDate)); //Print  as in05/04/2014
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would like it in the format "dd/MM/yyyy" however when I tried to do date.format(newDate) I got the error: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: What is your code looking like? Helps if you paste the full section